# Can i assign in 2 variables at the same time in C++?

Tags: c++

```
int DFS(a, b,c,d)
{
    first=a+b;
    second=c+d;
    return(first,second);
}

solution, cost_limit = DFS(a, b,c,d);
```

can I do something like this ? and how?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking here. I would suggest you explain what you mean by assign, and what you mean by a variable.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In C++11 you can use the tuple types and `tie` for that.

```
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, int> DFS (int a, int b, int c, int d)
{
    return std::make_tuple(a + b, c + d);
}

...

int solution, cost_limit;
std::tie(solution, cost_limit) = DFS(a, b, c, d);
```

Comment: If C++11 is not an option, the [Boost Tuple library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) provides these features.

Comment: If C++11 is not an option, you still can use C++03's `std::pair<int, int>`

Comment: @Antionio: but there's no `tie` in C++03, so it comes out looking pretty ugly: `std::pair<int, int> result = DFS(a,b,c,d); solution = result.first; cost_limit = result.second;`.

Comment: You could use TR1, I think that one also features the tuple library (with `tie`)

Comment: in C++17, use structured declarations with pair

Answer (score 16):

With C++17, you can unpack a pair or a tuple

```cpp
auto[i, j] = pair<int, int>{1, 2};
cout << i << j << endl; //prints 12
auto[l, m, n] = tuple<int, int, int>{1, 2, 3};
cout << l << m << n << endl; //prints 123
```

Comment: And you don't need the `<int, int>` anymore BTW: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270563/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdmake-pair-vs-the-constructor-of-stdpair/41521422#41521422

Comment: This is bundled with declaration. The question is how to assign to existing variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this two ways:

1. Create a struct with two values and return it:

   ```
   struct result
   {
       int first;
       int second;
   };

   struct result DFS(a, b, c, d)
   {            
       // code
   }
   ```
2. Have out parameters:

   ```
   void DFS(a, b, c, d, int& first, int& second)
   {
       // assigning first and second will be visible outside
   }
   ```

   call with:

   ```
   DFS(a, b, c, d, first, second);
   ```

Comment: This is clearly not what the OP is asking for.  He's asking for returning two separate values into two separate variables.

Comment: This is not what he asked for. He wants the pythonic way, meaning `solution = first; cost_limit = second;`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should be know is that if a,b,c,d are not base types, but instances of a class you defined, let's say Foo, and you overload the = operator of the class, you must ensure the fact that the operator will return a reference to the object which is assigned, or else you will not be able to chain assignments ( solution = cost_limit = DFS(..) will only assign to cost_limit). The = operator should look like this:

```
Foo& Foo::operator =(const Foo& other)
    {
       //do stuff
       return other;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If C++11 is not possible, it's possible to use references.

By passing a reference to variables in parameters.

```
int DFS(int a, int b, int c, int d, int &cost_limit)
{
    cost_limit = c + d;
    return a + b;
}

int solution, cost_limit;

solution = DFS(a, b, c, d, cost_limit);
```