# What is the purpose of std::make_pair vs the constructor of std::pair?

Tags: c++, stl, std-pair

What is the purpose of `std::make_pair`?

Why not just do `std::pair<int, char>(0, 'a')`?

Is there any difference between the two methods?

Comment: In C++11, you can almost entirely do without make_pair. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21995963/2288585).

Comment: In C++17, `std::make_pair` is redundant.  There is an answer below that details this.

Comment: **TL;DR:** Just use curly braces. ;) `{ 0, 'a' }` (Anyone who's ever coded JavaScript for some time will especially love this.)

Comment: `std::make_pair(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend())` compared to `std::pair<std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator, std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator>(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend())`?

Answer (score 213, accepted):

***(This answer is only correct for C++14 and earlier standards, due to [CTAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctad))***

The difference is that with `std::pair` you need to specify the types of both elements, whereas `std::make_pair` will create a pair with the type of the elements that are passed to it, without you needing to tell it. That's what I could gather from various docs anyways.

See this example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/make_pair/

```
pair <int,int> one;
pair <int,int> two;

one = make_pair (10,20);
two = make_pair (10.5,'A'); // ok: implicit conversion from pair<double,char>
```

Aside from the implicit conversion bonus of it, if you didn't use make_pair you'd have to do

```
one = pair<int,int>(10,20)
```

every time you assigned to one, which would be annoying over time...

Comment: Actually, the types should be deduced at compile time without the need to specify.

Comment: @Tor Yeah, I know how to use both of them, I was just curious if there was a reason for `std::make_pair`. Apparently it is just for convenience.

Comment: I think you can do `one = {10, 20}` nowadays but I don't have a C++11 compiler handy to check it.

Comment: Also note that `make_pair` works with unnamed types, including structs, unions, lambdas, and other doodads.

Comment: _"The difference is ... you need to specify the types of both elements"_ This answer is only correct for C++14 and earlier versions.

Comment: You could indeed do this in C++11 
one = {10, 20};
But not this:
one = std::pair{10,20); // works in C++17

Answer (score 61):

**Class template arguments could not be inferred from the constructor before C++17**

Before C++17 you could not write something like:

```
std::pair p(1, 'a');
```

since that would infer template types from the constructor arguments, you had to write it explicitly as:

```
std::pair<int,char> p(1, 'a');
```

C++17 makes that syntax possible, and therefore `make_pair` redundant.

Before C++17, `std::make_pair` allowed us to write less verbose code:

```
MyLongClassName1 o1;
MyLongClassName2 o2;
auto p = std::make_pair(o1, o2);
```

instead of the more verbose:

```
std::pair<MyLongClassName1,MyLongClassName2> p{o1, o2};
```

which repeats the types, and can be very long.

Type inference works in that pre-C++17 case because `make_pair` is not a constructor.

`make_pair` is essentially equivalent to:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
std::pair<T1, T2> my_make_pair(T1 t1, T2 t2) {
    return std::pair<T1, T2>(t1, t2);
}
```

The same concept applies to `inserter` vs `insert_iterator`.

See also:

- [Why not infer template parameter from constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984394/why-not-infer-template-parameter-from-constructor)
- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Object_Generator

**Minimal example**

To make things more concrete, we can observe the problem minimally with:

main.cpp

```
template <class MyType>
struct MyClass {
    MyType i;
    MyClass(MyType i) : i(i) {}
};

template<class MyType>
MyClass<MyType> make_my_class(MyType i) {
    return MyClass<MyType>(i);
}

int main() {
    MyClass<int> my_class(1);
}
```

then:

```
g++-8 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++17 main.cpp
```

compiles happily, but:

```
g++-8 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++14 main.cpp
```

fails with:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:13:13: error: missing template arguments before ‘my_class’
     MyClass my_class(1);
             ^~~~~~~~
```

and requires instead to work:

```
MyClass<int> my_class(1);
```

or the helper:

```
auto my_class = make_my_class(1);
```

which uses a regular function instead of a constructor.

**Difference for `std::reference_wrapper`**

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270563/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdmake-pair-vs-the-constructor-of-stdpair/41521422?noredirect=1#comment107679675_41521422) mentions that `std::make_pair` unwraps `std::reference_wrapper` while the constructor does not, so that's one difference. TODO example.

Tested with [GCC 8.1.0, Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028601/install-gcc-8-only-on-ubuntu-18-04/1087116#1087116).

Comment: _"C++17 makes that syntax possible, and therefore make_pair redundant."_ - Why is it that `std::make_pair` did not become deprecated in C++17?

Comment: @andreee I'm not sure, possible reason is that it creates no trouble so no need to break old code? But I'm not familiar with C++ committee rationale, ping me if you find something.

Comment: One useful thing that I have come across is that being able to specify the types with std::make_pair<T1, T2>(o1, o2) prevents the user from making the mistake of passing types o1 or o2 that can't implicitly be cast to T1 or T2. For instance passing a negative number to an unsigned int. -Wsign-conversion -Werror will not catch this error with std::pair constructor in c++11 however it will catch the error if std::make_pair is used.

Comment: `make_pair` unwraps reference wrappers, so it's different from CTAD actually.

Answer (score 53):

As @MSalters replied above, you can now use curly braces to do this in C++11 (just verified this with a C++11 compiler):

```
pair<int, int> p = {1, 2};
```

Answer (score 26):

There is no difference between using `make_pair` and explicitly calling the `pair` constructor with specified type arguments. `std::make_pair` is more convenient when the types are verbose because  a template method has type deduction based on its given parameters.
For example,

```
std::vector< std::pair< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> > > vecOfPair;
std::vector<int> emptyV;

// shorter
vecOfPair.push_back(std::make_pair(emptyV, emptyV));

 // longer
vecOfPair.push_back(std::pair< std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> >(emptyV, emptyV));
```

Comment: Even shorter: `vecOfPair.emplace_back(emptyV, emptyV);`

Answer (score 21):

It's worth noting that this is a common idiom in C++ template programming. It's known as the Object Generator idiom, you can find more information and a nice example [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Object_Generator).

**Edit** As someone suggested in the comments (since removed) the following is a slightly modified extract from the link in case it breaks.

An Object Generator allows creation of objects without explicitly specifying their types. It is based on a useful property of function templates which class templates don't have: The type parameters of a function template are deduced automatically from its actual parameters. `std::make_pair` is a simple example that returns an instance of the `std::pair` template depending on the actual parameters of the `std::make_pair` function.

```
template <class T, class U>
std::pair <T, U> 
make_pair(T t, U u)
{
  return std::pair <T, U> (t,u);
}
```

Comment: @duck Actually `&&` since C++11.

Answer (score 5):

make_pair creates an extra copy over the direct constructor. I always typedef my pairs to provide simple syntax.
This shows the difference (example by Rampal Chaudhary):

```
class Sample
{
    static int _noOfObjects;

    int _objectNo;
public:
    Sample() :
        _objectNo( _noOfObjects++ )
    {
        std::cout<<"Inside default constructor of object "<<_objectNo<<std::endl;
    }

    Sample( const Sample& sample) :
    _objectNo( _noOfObjects++ )
    {
        std::cout<<"Inside copy constructor of object "<<_objectNo<<std::endl;
    }

    ~Sample()
    {
        std::cout<<"Destroying object "<<_objectNo<<std::endl;
    }
};
int Sample::_noOfObjects = 0;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Sample sample;
    std::map<int,Sample> map;

    map.insert( std::make_pair( 1, sample) );
    //map.insert( std::pair<int,Sample>( 1, sample) );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that the extra copy will be elided in all cases, if the optimization settings of the compiler are high enough.

Comment: Why would you ever want to rely on compiler optimizations for correctness?

Comment: I get the same results with both versions, and with `std::move` just inside `insert` and/or around what would be a reference to `sample`. It is only when I change `std::map<int,Sample>` to `std::map<int,Sample const&>` that I reduce the number of constructed objects, and only when I delete the copy constructor that I eliminate all copies (obviously). After making both of those changes, my result includes one call to the default constructor and two calls to the destructor for the same object. I think I must be missing something. (g++ 5.4.1, c++11)

Comment: FWIW I agree that optimization and correctness should be completely independent, as this is exactly the kind of code you write as a sanity check after different optimization levels produce inconsistent results.

In general I would recommend `emplace` instead of `insert` if you're just constructing a value to insert immediately (and you don't want extra instances.) It's not my area of expertise, if I can even say I have one, but the copy/move semantics introduced by C++11 have helped me a lot.

Comment: I believe I am encountering exactly the same issue and after debugging for about the entire evening, I finally came here.

Answer (score 2):

starting from c++11 just use uniform initialization for pairs. So instead of:

```
std::make_pair(1, 2);
```

or

```
std::pair<int, int>(1, 2);
```

just use

```
{1, 2};
```

Comment: `{1, 2}` can be used to initialize a pair, but does not commit for type pair. I.e. when using auto you have to commit to a type on the RHS:  `auto p = std::pair{"Tokyo"s, 9.00};`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm never going to use `std::make_pair` again because it's "broken" (from my perspective - at least it's unintuitive). Consider the following example

You have a backing storage, or a string pool of

```cpp
using Id = int;
std::vector<std::string> string_pool;
std::map<std::string_view, Id> str_to_id_map;
```

If you attempt to insert into `std::map` like so;

```cpp
str_to_id_map.insert(std::make_pair(string_pool.back(), 42));
```

This will fail, spectacularly. It will *first* create a copy of the `std::string` which *then* will be turned into a `std::string_view` - and now, that string_view is pointing to "anywhere". It might work, it might not work. I tested this just recently.

However, if you instead use

```cpp
str_to_id_map.insert({string_pool.back(), 42});
```

This will correctly be deduced by the Compiler Gods as a `string_view` over the string_pool contents and will work - no intermediary copy of a `std::string`, turned into a `string_view`

My lesson or takeaway I gather from this is - never, ever, ever, ever use std::make_pair.