# Use of `std::make_pair` in std::pair : C++ STL

Tags: c++, stl, std-pair

I noticed many a times that whenever one needs to assign values to a (new)`std::pair`, `std::make_pair` is used. But I did not find any use of the `make_pair` function, since we can directly input values to a pair, and modify them as we like.
For example:

```
std::pair<int,int> newp;
std::cin>>newp.first>>newp.second;
newp.first = -1;
```

Then what exactly is the use of this function?

Comment: Now try doing this with a type that doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: @milleniumbug: Valid observation, but you have the same problem with `std::make_pair`. Fundamentally, it's a design problem between language and library. You simply cannot write a heterogeneous list of object declarations initialized sequentially by an input stream. the closest you could get is to define ctors taking a stream argument, and conversion operations on the stream for the built-in types. You'd still have to repeat the stream name a lot with that style.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of std::make\_pair vs the constructor of std::pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270563/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdmake-pair-vs-the-constructor-of-stdpair)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we can directly input values to a pair, and modify them as we like.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> std::pair<int,int> newp;
> std::cin>>newp.first>>newp.second;
> newp.first = -1;
> ```

Some problems I can think of:

1. You don't always have a stream object ready. `std::cin` is a very *special* case, and `std::make_pair` is a very *generic* function.
2. Who says that both types in the pair support `operator>>`?
3. Const correctness. You may want to have a `const` pair.

Let's put these three things together to create a non-compiling example:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int i;
};

struct Bar
{
    double d;
};

void printPair(std::pair<Foo, Bar> const& pair)
{
    std::cout << pair.first.i << " " << pair.second.d << "\n";
}

void createAndPrintPairTwice(Foo const& foo, Bar const& bar)
{
    // error 1: no std::cin, need to use foo and bar
    // error 2: no operator>> for Foo or Bar
    // error 3: cannot change pair values after initialisation
    std::pair<Foo, Bar> const newp;
    std::cin >> newp.first >> newp.second;
    printPair(newp);
    printPair(newp);
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.i = 1;
    Bar bar;
    bar.d = 1.5;
    createAndPrintPairTwice(foo, bar);
}
```

`std::make_pair` solves all three problems and makes the code much nicer to read. Note that you don't have to repeat the pair's template arguments:

```
void createAndPrintPairTwice(Foo const& foo, Bar const& bar)
{
    std::pair<Foo, Bar> const pair = std::make_pair(foo, bar);
    printPair(pair);
    printPair(pair);
}
```

What's true is that C++11 has rendered `std::make_pair` much less useful than before, because you can now also write:

```
void createAndPrintPairTwice(Foo const& foo, Bar const& bar)
{
    auto const pair = std::pair<Foo, Bar> { foo, bar };
    printPair(pair);
    printPair(pair);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I get it now. It's useful only at some places now!

Answer (score 6):

[`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) is used to create a `std::pair` object with the specified values.

> Creates a std::pair object, deducing the target type from the types of arguments.

As a template function which supports automatic template argument type deducing, it allows you omit specifying the target template argument type. e.g.,

```
auto p1 = std::make_pair(1, 2);  // p1 is std::pair<int, int> with value {1, 2}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is, its advantage is called [Template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). It saves a bit of typing and lets you use `auto`. *class-template* arguments must be explicitly specified, *functions*, mustn't.

---

But it becomes redundant with [C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17), because we will have [Template Argument Deduction For *class-templates*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html)