# Why does make_pair<int,int> fail in C++ 11?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

The following piece of code works fine when compiling as C++ 98, but it fails as C++ 11. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int u = 1;
    pair<int, int> p = make_pair<int, int>(0, u);
    cout << p.first << " " << p.second << "\n";
}
```

The error message from g++ (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0 is:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cpp:9:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_pair<int, int>(int, int&)’
  pair<int, int> p = make_pair<int, int>(0, u);
                                             ^
```

I'm aware that I can compile this simply by removing the template specifier from `make_pair` and letting the compiler decide the types on its own. But I'm interested in understanding what changes from C++ 98 to C++ 11 that makes this code no longer compliant.

Comment: Do you compile with -std=c++11 flag or what?

Comment: @Boki I tested with `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++98`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[std::make_pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) has changed between `c++03` and `c++11`.

Your code fails as `std::make_pair` expects `T&&` and `U&&`, where `T` and `U` are template type parameters.
Like

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
std::pair<V1,V2> make_pair(T&& argT, U&& argU);
```

Still if you want to specify both of these parameter use `pair<int, int>`

Example -

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int u = 1;
    pair<int, int> p = pair<int, int>(0, u);
    cout << p.first << " " << p.second << "\n";
}
```

You can refer here for more details - [utility-make_pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/)

Comment: You version compiles with `-std=c++98`. So you could always have instantiated the pair with the constructor. Why was `make_pair` required?

Comment: Using `make_pair` you can use curly braces to simply add elements without typing whole thing. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270563/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdmake-pair-vs-the-constructor-of-stdpair)

Answer (score 7):

Before c++11 there was

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
std::pair<T1,T2> make_pair( T1 t, T2 u );
```

you defined T1 and T2 to be: `int`, so `int` can take Lvalues and Rvalues.

Since c++11 you have

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
std::pair<V1,V2> make_pair( T1&& t, T2&& u );
```

because `T2` was defined as `int`, so `int&&` as second parameter can take only Rvalues. But `u` is Lvalue.

Answer (score 2):

You are not supposed to pass type arguments to `make_pair`; it is intended to deduce its arguments.  If you want to make something that creates exactly of a type, just do `std::pair<int, int>`.

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) rvalue references and perfect forwarding was added; `make_pair<int,int>` has signature `(int&&, int&&)`.  These are both rvalue references, and cannot bind to an lvalue (like `u`).

`make_pair<int, int&>(0, u)` would compile, and produce a `pair<int, int>`, because `make_pair` creates a pair of value-types.

Without rvalue references in [c++03](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03), this problem cannot happen.  Probably `make_pair` was `make_pair( A const&, B const& )` instead of `make_pair( A&&, B&& )`.