# Since brace-initializataion is possible, why do we still have std::make_pair? What's the purpose or advantage of it?

Tags: c++, c++11

As we know, both of these ways to assign are possible. Why we still have `std::make_pair`?

```
std::pair<int, char> myPair1 = { 1,'a' };
std::pair<int, char> myPair2 = std::make_pair(1, 'a');
```

I'm not here to criticize the syntax. I just really want to know what's the advantage for us to use `std::make_pair` instead of directly using the curly braces.

Actually, I think the only advantage is that it can make our code more readable, like you're passing the parameter with `std::make_pair` instead of the curly braces. It makes it easier to tell that you're passing a pair. Since the curly brace can refer to something more, like a tuple or array.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270563/what-is-the-purpose-of-stdmake-pair-vs-the-constructor-of-stdpair?

Comment: @康桓瑋 the second answer, in particular.  Specifically not the accepted answer.

Comment: _why do we still have std::make_pair?_ Also, so as not to break existing code, I guess

Comment: If they removed every feature that was no longer considered the best way to do something, we'd have a pretty nice language, but that language's compiler wouldn't be able to compile most of the C++ code out there anymore and it would probably need to be named something else.

Comment: Do note, that for `std::pair<int, char> myPair2 = std::make_pair(1, 'a');`, we can save a lot of typing by using `auto myPair2 = std::make_pair(1, 'a');`

Comment: Nothing is ever deprecated for cosmetic reasons.

Comment: `make_pair` is not without its uses in C++17 still. We cannot omit arguments and do `pair<std::string>{"aa", 1}` - it's all or nothing. So if I really want a `std::string` there instead of a character pointer, while still deducing the second type, `std::make_pair<std::string>("aaa", 1)` has its utility and charm.

Comment: The answer from Jeremy Friesner is awesome.Thanks a lot.