# Assigning 2 pre-declared variables to function return

Tags: c++

I have a function that returns `std::pair<int, int>`. I also have 2 pre-declared variables `x` and `y`. I want to do something like this:

```
int x;
int y;

if (flag) {
  x, y = func_that_returns_pair(some args);
} else {
  x, y = func_that_returns_pair(some different args);
}
```

I looked at [Can i assign in 2 variables at the same time in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833559/can-i-assign-in-2-variables-at-the-same-time-in-c), and in C++11, you can use `std::tie`. I don't think the `auto [x, y]` approach would work here since `x, y` are already declared and there's if/else conditioning here. Is there another way to do this besides using `std::tie`?

Comment: Could you explain what the issue is with `std::tie` and what an alternative should do differently?

Comment: @cigien no issue. just seeing if there's any more modern approaches post C++11

Comment: *"since `x, y` are already declared"* -- Do they have to be already declared? There is a difference between updating their values and giving them their initial values (the conditional is more of a challenge than an obstacle).

Comment: @JaMiT they don't already have to be declared, but they do have to remain in scope after the if/else condition since they're used afterwards, so I think the only way to do that is to declare them beforehand?

Comment: @roulette01 *"I think the only way to do that is to declare them beforehand?"* -- Many problems can be solved by adding an extra layer of abstraction, such as a wrapper function (as in the answer by StoryTeller) or even the ternary operator (as in the answer by Chris). ;)  It's best to (identify and) remove unsubstantiated assumptions from your written requirements. It worked out this time, but in the future, questioning assumptions might be essential.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there another way to do this besides using `std::tie`?

Yes, you can use a `std::pair` with references:

```cpp
std::pair<int&, int&>(x, y) = func_that_returns_pair(...);
```

... or a `std::tuple` with references:

```cpp
std::tuple<int&, int&>(x, y) = func_that_returns_pair(...);
```

Answer (score 5):

You might use a conditional/ternary/whatever-you-want-to-call-it expression to *initialize* `x` and `y` using the destructuring syntax.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

std::pair<int, int> foo() {
    return std::make_pair(6, 7);
}

std::pair<int, int> bar() {
    return std::make_pair(3, 4);
}

int main() {
    auto [x, y] = true ? foo() : bar();

    std::cout << x << y << std::endl;
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

constexpr std::pair<int, int> foo() { return {6, 7}; }

constexpr std::pair<int, int> bar() { return {3, 4}; }

int main() {
    auto [x, y] = true ? foo() : bar();

    std::cout << x << y << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
67
```

Answer (score 2):

> I don't think the `auto [x, y]` approach would work here since `x, y` are already declared

For the code as written, that's true. And this is a recurring problem in fact, since C++ has a fair few things that can only be initialized, not re-assigned (not even a `std::tie`-like solution exists for constant objects).

Fortunately, we can always put such logic - no matter how complex - into functions that return the initial value for our declaration. And since C++11, we can even write the function inline as an immediately invoked lambda.

```
auto [x, y] = [&]{
  if (/*some condition*/) {
    return func_that_returns_pair(/*some args*/);
  }

  if(/*some other condition*/){
    return func_that_returns_pair(/*some different args*/);
  }

  return func_that_returns_pair(/*Some default args*/);
}();
```

Very handy in a quick refactor, since it doesn't require passing a lot of context into the call (we can just capture that context in scope of the declaration).

Comment: ahhh totally forgot that lambdas can be used here.